# In need of a Labelencoder code to fix the InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error when Using deeplabv3+ for a 4 class semantic segmentation

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, semantic-segmentation, deeplab

Am running a 4 class semantic segmentation problem using Deeplabv3+ and I get the graph execution error as soon as the training starts.
I have identified the problem after searching the web for solutions. The problem is with the labels. My labels are 2, 4, 6, 8 instead of 0,1,2,3.
Currently the model trains after adjusting to `num_classes: 9` so as to cater for all the labels. sounds weird since I should encode the labels to 0,1,2,3. I have failed to encode the labels to to fit in my main code so as to get rid of the invalid labels.
**Can some help me with the script and where to fix it in my code?** Thank you :)

**This is the code that i generated and i will be glad if anyone goes through it**

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import albumentations as A
from glob import glob
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
path = "D:/K/deeplabv3plus/datasets"
os.chdir(path)

os.listdir(os.path.join('128_patches', 'masks'))[:924]
os.listdir(os.path.join('128_patches', 'images'))[:924]

config = {
    'IMG_PATH': os.path.join('128_patches', 'images'),
    'LABEL_PATH': os.path.join('128_patches', 'masks'),
    'NUM_CLASSES': 4,
    'BATCH_SIZE': 2,
    'IMAGE_SIZE': 128
}

##### Building Dataset
image_paths =  glob(os.path.join(config['IMG_PATH'], '*'), recursive=True)
mask_paths =  glob(os.path.join(config['LABEL_PATH'], '*'), recursive=True)

#image_paths_train, image_paths_test, mask_paths_train, mask_paths_test = train_test_split(image_paths, mask_paths, shuffle=True)
image_paths_train1, image_paths_test1, mask_paths_train1, mask_paths_test1 = train_test_split(image_paths, mask_paths, test_size=0.15)
image_paths_train, image_paths_test, mask_paths_train, mask_paths_test = train_test_split(image_paths_train1, mask_paths_train1, test_size=0.15)

config['DATASET_LENGTH'] = len(image_paths_train)
def preprocess(image_path, mask_path):
img = tf.io.read_file(image_path)
img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img, channels=3)
img = tf.image.resize(img, size=[config['IMAGE_SIZE'], config['IMAGE_SIZE']])
img = tf.cast(img, tf.float32) / 255.0
    
mask = tf.io.read_file(mask_path)
# Only one channel for masks, denoting the class and NOT image colors
mask = tf.image.decode_png(mask, channels=1)
mask = tf.image.resize(mask, size=[config['IMAGE_SIZE'], config['IMAGE_SIZE']])
mask = tf.cast(mask, tf.float32)
return img, mask

def augment_dataset_tf(img, mask):
     #  Augmentations should always be performed on both an input image and a mask if applied at all
    if tf.random.uniform(()) > 0.5:
        img = tf.image.flip_left_right(img)
        mask = tf.image.flip_left_right(mask)
    if tf.random.uniform(()) > 0.5:
        img = tf.image.flip_up_down(img)
        mask = tf.image.flip_up_down(mask)
    if tf.random.uniform(()) > 0.5:
        img = tf.image.rot90(img)
        mask = tf.image.rot90(mask)
            
    return img, mask

def albumentations(img, mask):
    # Augmentation pipeline - each of these has an adjustable probability
    # of being applied, regardless of other transforms
    transform = A.Compose([
        A.HorizontalFlip(p=0.5),
        A.RandomBrightnessContrast(p=0.3),
        A.Transpose(p=0.5),
        A.VerticalFlip(p=0.5),
        A.HorizontalFlip(p=0.5),
        A.Rotate(limit=70),
        # CoarseDropout is the new Cutout implementation
        A.CoarseDropout(p=0.5, max_holes=12, max_height=24, max_width=24)
    ])
    
    # Apply transforms and extract image and mask
    transformed = transform(image=img, mask=mask)
    transformed_image = transformed['image']
    transformed_mask = transformed['mask']
    
    # Cast to TF Floats and return
    transformed_image = tf.cast(transformed_image, tf.float32)
    transformed_mask = tf.cast(transformed_mask, tf.float32)
    return transformed_image, transformed_mask

def create_dataset_tf(images, masks, augment):
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((images, masks)).shuffle(len(images))
    dataset = dataset.map(preprocess, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
    if augment:
        dataset = dataset.map(apply_albumentations, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
        dataset = dataset.batch(config['BATCH_SIZE'], drop_remainder=True).prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE).repeat()
    else:
        dataset = dataset.batch(config['BATCH_SIZE'], drop_remainder=True).prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
    return dataset

def apply_albumentations(img, mask):
    aug_img, aug_mask = tf.numpy_function(func=albumentations, inp=[img, mask], Tout=[tf.float32, tf.float32])
    aug_img = tf.ensure_shape(aug_img, shape=[config['IMAGE_SIZE'], config['IMAGE_SIZE'], 3])
    aug_mask = tf.ensure_shape(aug_mask, shape=[config['IMAGE_SIZE'], config['IMAGE_SIZE'], 1])
    return aug_img, aug_mask

train_set = create_dataset_tf(image_paths_train, mask_paths_train, augment=False)
test_set = create_dataset_tf(image_paths_test, mask_paths_test, augment=False)

for img_batch, mask_batch in train_set.take(2):
    for i in range(len(img_batch)):
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2)
        ax[0].imshow(img_batch[i].numpy())
        ax[1].imshow(mask_batch[i].numpy())
        
# Turns into atrous_block with dilation_rate > 1
def conv_block(block_input, num_filters=256, kernel_size=(3, 3), dilation_rate=1, padding="same"):
    x = keras.layers.Conv2D(num_filters, kernel_size=kernel_size, dilation_rate=dilation_rate, padding="same")(block_input)
    x = keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = keras.layers.Activation('relu')(x)
    return x

# Atrous Spatial Pyramid Pooling
def ASPP(inputs):
    # 4 conv blocks with dilation rates at `[1, 6, 12, 18]`
    conv_1 = conv_block(inputs, kernel_size=(1, 1), dilation_rate=1)
    conv_6 = conv_block(inputs, kernel_size=(3, 3), dilation_rate=6)
    conv_12 = conv_block(inputs, kernel_size=(3, 3), dilation_rate=12)
    conv_18 = conv_block(inputs, kernel_size=(3, 3), dilation_rate=18)
    
    dims = inputs.shape
    # Image Pooling -> (256, 256, 3) -> (1, 1, filter_num) -> (32, 32, 256)
    x = keras.layers.AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(dims[-3], dims[-2]))(inputs)
    x = conv_block(x, kernel_size=1)
    out_pool = keras.layers.UpSampling2D(size=(dims[-3] // x.shape[1], dims[-2] // x.shape[2]))(x)

    x = keras.layers.Concatenate()([conv_1, conv_6, conv_12, conv_18, out_pool])
    return conv_block(x, kernel_size=1)

def define_deeplabv3_plus(image_size, num_classes, backbone):
    model_input = keras.Input(shape=(image_size, image_size, 3))
    
    if backbone == 'resnet':
        resnet101 = keras.applications.ResNet152(
            weights="imagenet", 
            include_top=False, 
            input_tensor=model_input)
        x = resnet101.get_layer("conv4_block6_2_relu").output
        low_level = resnet101.get_layer("conv2_block3_2_relu").output
        
    elif backbone == 'effnet':
        effnet = keras.applications.EfficientNetV2B1(
            weights="imagenet", 
             include_top=False, 
             input_tensor=model_input)
        x = effnet.get_layer("block5e_activation").output
        low_level = effnet.get_layer("block2a_expand_activation").output
        
    aspp_result = ASPP(x)
    upsampled_aspp = keras.layers.UpSampling2D(size=(4, 4))(aspp_result)
    
    low_level = conv_block(low_level, num_filters=48, kernel_size=1)

    x = keras.layers.Concatenate()([upsampled_aspp, low_level])
    x = conv_block(x)
    x = keras.layers.UpSampling2D(size=(4, 4))(x)
    model_output = keras.layers.Conv2D(num_classes, kernel_size=(1, 1), padding="same", activation='softmax')(x)
    return keras.Model(inputs=model_input, outputs=model_output)



#model = define_deeplabv3_plus(config['IMAGE_SIZE'], config['NUM_CLASSES'], 'resnet')
model = define_deeplabv3_plus(config['IMAGE_SIZE'], config['NUM_CLASSES'], 'effnet')
model.summary()

from keras import backend as K

def dice_coef(y_true, y_pred, smooth=1e-7):
    y_true_f = K.flatten(K.one_hot(K.cast(y_true, 'int32'), num_classes=config['NUM_CLASSES'])[...,1:])
    y_pred_f = K.flatten(y_pred[...,1:])
    intersect = K.sum(y_true_f * y_pred_f, axis=-1)
    denom = K.sum(y_true_f + y_pred_f, axis=-1)
    return K.mean((2. * intersect / (denom + smooth)))

def dice_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return 1 - dice_coef(y_true, y_pred)

class MeanIoU(tf.keras.metrics.MeanIoU):
    def __init__(self,
               y_true=None,
               y_pred=None,
               num_classes=None,
               name=None,
               dtype=None):
        super(MeanIoU, self).__init__(num_classes = num_classes,name=name, dtype=dtype)

    def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
        y_pred = tf.math.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1)
        return super().update_state(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight)
    
reduceLr = keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(patience=5, factor=0.3, monitor='val_sparse_categorical_accuracy')
early_stopping = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=10, monitor='val_sparse_categorical_accuracy', restore_best_weights=True)

model.compile(
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-3),
    #loss=soft_dice_loss,
    loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
    metrics=["sparse_categorical_accuracy", 
              MeanIoU(num_classes=config['NUM_CLASSES']),
              dice_coef])

history = model.fit(train_set, 
                    epochs=100, 
                    steps_per_epoch=int(config['DATASET_LENGTH']/config['BATCH_SIZE']), 
                    validation_data=test_set,
                    callbacks=[reduceLr, early_stopping])
```

**Now, below is the error that comes up the moment i begin to train the model**

```
Epoch 1/100

2022-10-17 09:57:16.605349: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:384] Loaded cuDNN version 8500
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Windows\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_10008\204393382.py", line 12, in <module>
    history = model.fit(train_set,

  File "C:\Users\Windows\anaconda3\envs\Kal\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None

  File "C:\Users\Windows\anaconda3\envs\Kal\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py", line 54, in quick_execute
    tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,

InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'confusion_matrix/assert_less/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Windows\anaconda3\envs\Kal\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
      return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
    File "C:\Users\Windows\anaconda3\envs\Kal\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
    File "C:\Users\Windows\anaconda3\envs\Kal\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\console\__main__.py", line 24, in <module>
      start.main()
    File "C:\Users\Windows\anaconda3\envs\Kal\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\console\start.py", line 332, in main
      kernel.start()
    File "C:\Users\Windows\anaconda3\envs\Kal\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 677, in start
      self.io_loop.start()
    File "C:\Users\Windows\anaconda3\envs\Kal\lib\site-packages\tornado\platform\asyncio.py", line 199, in start
      self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
    File "C:\Users\Windows\anaconda3\envs\Kal\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 600, in run_forever
      self._run_once()
    File "C:\Users\Windows\anaconda3\envs\Kal\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1896, in _run_once
      handle._run()
    File "C:\Users\Windows\anaconda3\envs\Kal\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 80, in _run
      self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
    File "C:\Users\Windows\anaconda3\envs\Kal\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 471, in dispatch_queue
      await self.process_one()
    File "C:\Users\Windows\anaconda3\envs\Kal\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 460, in process_one
      await dispatch(*args)
    File "C:\Users\Windows\anaconda3\envs\Kal\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 367, in dispatch_shell
      await result
    File "C:\Users\Windows\anaconda3\envs\Kal\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 662, in execute_request
      reply_content = await reply_content
    File "C:\Users\Windows\anaconda3\envs\Kal\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\ipkernel.py", line 360, in do_execute
      res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
    File "C:\Users\Windows\anaconda3\envs\Kal\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\zmqshell.py", line 532, in run_cell
      return super().run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\Windows\anaconda3\envs\Kal\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2914, in run_cell
      result = self._run_cell(
    File "C:\Users\Windows\anaconda3\envs\Kal\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2960, in _run_cell
      return runner(coro)
    File "C:\Users\Windows\anaconda3\envs\Kal\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\async_helpers.py", line 78, in _pseudo_sync_runner
      coro.send(None)
    File "C:\Users\Windows\anaconda3\envs\Kal\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3185, in run_cell_async
      has_raised = await self.run_ast_nodes(code_ast.body, cell_name,
    File "C:\Users\Windows\anaconda3\envs\Kal\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3377, in run_ast_nodes
      if (await self.run_code(code, result,  async_=asy)):
    File "C:\Users\Windows\anaconda3\envs\Kal\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3457, in run_code
      exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
    File "C:\Users\Windows\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_10008\204393382.py", line 12, in <module>
      history = model.fit(train_set,
    File "C:\Users\Windows\anaconda3\envs\Kal\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\Windows\anaconda3\envs\Kal\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1409, in fit
      tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
    File "C:\Users\Windows\anaconda3\envs\Kal\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1051, in train_function
      return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "C:\Users\Windows\anaconda3\envs\Kal\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1040, in step_function
      outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "C:\Users\Windows\anaconda3\envs\Kal\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1030, in run_step
      outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "C:\Users\Windows\anaconda3\envs\Kal\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 894, in train_step
      return self.compute_metrics(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "C:\Users\Windows\anaconda3\envs\Kal\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 987, in compute_metrics
      self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "C:\Users\Windows\anaconda3\envs\Kal\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\compile_utils.py", line 501, in update_state
      metric_obj.update_state(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=mask)
    File "C:\Users\Windows\anaconda3\envs\Kal\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\metrics_utils.py", line 70, in decorated
      update_op = update_state_fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\Windows\anaconda3\envs\Kal\lib\site-packages\keras\metrics\base_metric.py", line 140, in update_state_fn
      return ag_update_state(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\Windows\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_10008\1378111743.py", line 12, in update_state
      return super().update_state(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "C:\Users\Windows\anaconda3\envs\Kal\lib\site-packages\keras\metrics\metrics.py", line 2494, in update_state
      current_cm = tf.math.confusion_matrix(
Node: 'confusion_matrix/assert_less/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert'
Detected at node 'confusion_matrix/assert_less/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Windows\anaconda3\envs\Kal\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
      return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
    File "C:\Users\Windows\anaconda3\envs\Kal\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
    File "C:\Users\Windows\anaconda3\envs\Kal\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\console\__main__.py", line 24, in <module>
      start.main()
    File "C:\Users\Windows\anaconda3\envs\Kal\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\console\start.py", line 332, in main
      kernel.start()
    File "C:\Users\Windows\anaconda3\envs\Kal\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 677, in start
      self.io_loop.start()
    File "C:\Users\Windows\anaconda3\envs\Kal\lib\site-packages\tornado\platform\asyncio.py", line 199, in start
      self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
    File "C:\Users\Windows\anaconda3\envs\Kal\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 600, in run_forever
      self._run_once()
    File "C:\Users\Windows\anaconda3\envs\Kal\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1896, in _run_once
      handle._run()
    File "C:\Users\Windows\anaconda3\envs\Kal\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 80, in _run
      self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
    File "C:\Users\Windows\anaconda3\envs\Kal\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 471, in dispatch_queue
      await self.process_one()
    File "C:\Users\Windows\anaconda3\envs\Kal\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 460, in process_one
      await dispatch(*args)
    File "C:\Users\Windows\anaconda3\envs\Kal\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 367, in dispatch_shell
      await result
    File "C:\Users\Windows\anaconda3\envs\Kal\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 662, in execute_request
      reply_content = await reply_content
    File "C:\Users\Windows\anaconda3\envs\Kal\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\ipkernel.py", line 360, in do_execute
      res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
    File "C:\Users\Windows\anaconda3\envs\Kal\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\zmqshell.py", line 532, in run_cell
      return super().run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\Windows\anaconda3\envs\Kal\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2914, in run_cell
      result = self._run_cell(
    File "C:\Users\Windows\anaconda3\envs\Kal\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2960, in _run_cell
      return runner(coro)
    File "C:\Users\Windows\anaconda3\envs\Kal\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\async_helpers.py", line 78, in _pseudo_sync_runner
      coro.send(None)
    File "C:\Users\Windows\anaconda3\envs\Kal\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3185, in run_cell_async
      has_raised = await self.run_ast_nodes(code_ast.body, cell_name,
    File "C:\Users\Windows\anaconda3\envs\Kal\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3377, in run_ast_nodes
      if (await self.run_code(code, result,  async_=asy)):
    File "C:\Users\Windows\anaconda3\envs\Kal\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3457, in run_code
      exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
    File "C:\Users\Windows\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_10008\204393382.py", line 12, in <module>
      history = model.fit(train_set,
    File "C:\Users\Windows\anaconda3\envs\Kal\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\Windows\anaconda3\envs\Kal\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1409, in fit
      tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
    File "C:\Users\Windows\anaconda3\envs\Kal\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1051, in train_function
      return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "C:\Users\Windows\anaconda3\envs\Kal\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1040, in step_function
      outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "C:\Users\Windows\anaconda3\envs\Kal\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1030, in run_step
      outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "C:\Users\Windows\anaconda3\envs\Kal\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 894, in train_step
      return self.compute_metrics(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "C:\Users\Windows\anaconda3\envs\Kal\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 987, in compute_metrics
      self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "C:\Users\Windows\anaconda3\envs\Kal\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\compile_utils.py", line 501, in update_state
      metric_obj.update_state(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=mask)
    File "C:\Users\Windows\anaconda3\envs\Kal\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\metrics_utils.py", line 70, in decorated
      update_op = update_state_fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\Windows\anaconda3\envs\Kal\lib\site-packages\keras\metrics\base_metric.py", line 140, in update_state_fn
      return ag_update_state(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\Windows\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_10008\1378111743.py", line 12, in update_state
      return super().update_state(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "C:\Users\Windows\anaconda3\envs\Kal\lib\site-packages\keras\metrics\metrics.py", line 2494, in update_state
      current_cm = tf.math.confusion_matrix(
Node: 'confusion_matrix/assert_less/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert'
2 root error(s) found.
  (0) INVALID_ARGUMENT:  assertion failed: [`labels` out of bound] [Condition x < y did not hold element-wise:] [x (confusion_matrix/control_dependency:0) = ] [6 6 6...] [y (confusion_matrix/Cast_2:0) = ] [4]
     [[{{node confusion_matrix/assert_less/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert}}]]
     [[confusion_matrix/assert_less_1/Assert/AssertGuard/pivot_f/_31/_61]]
  (1) INVALID_ARGUMENT:  assertion failed: [`labels` out of bound] [Condition x < y did not hold element-wise:] [x (confusion_matrix/control_dependency:0) = ] [6 6 6...] [y (confusion_matrix/Cast_2:0) = ] [4]
     [[{{node confusion_matrix/assert_less/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert}}]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference_train_function_17948]
```

I will be very glad if anyone can help with the debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your label by using

```
dataset = dataset.map(lambda x, y: (x, y/2-1), num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
```

inside the function **create_dataset_tf**. It will map the label from 2, 4, 6, 8 to 0, 1, 2, 3.

Comment: Thanks very much. it did the magic. sigh of relief :D

Comment: The technique is however not a permanent solution for encoding the labels. its impossible to compute the meanIoU for each class as it still brings up the issue of labels.

Comment: Have you tried to create a different dataset for a different number of classes?

Comment: Because i was able to get results with 9 classes, i went with that :D. now on something different. thank you though